# Is it correct in TFS/TFS Aggregator setting true both "make-requests-on-behalf-of-others-permission" and "authentication autoImpersonate"?

Tags: tfs, tfs-aggregator

I'm using TFS 2017 update 1 on premises + TFS Aggregator 2.2.1.
In order to properly use autoImpersonate set to true in TFSAggregator2.ServerPlugin.Policies, i.e.:

```
    <!--
    autoImpersonate false (default) use the TFS Service account, true the user requesting. (Optional)
    -->
    <authentication autoImpersonate="true" />
```

is it necessary to set the following permission to true for "Project Collection Valid Users" group?
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions#make-requests-on-behalf-of-others-permission

Answer (score 1):

> Make requests on behalf of others ▼
>
> **Can perform operations on behalf of other users or services.** Only assign to service accounts.

Yes, you need to set the permission to true.

---

*Besides,* *questions about general computing  software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.* Your could ask the question directly under the extension in marketplace or from GitHub.